# What is the meaning of demon names: yAtudAnAs and AtatAyins?

Tags: name, terminology, rakshasa

Demons are also called yAtudAnAs and AtatAyins. What are the meanings of these two terms and why demons are called so.

Comment: Yatudhanas are flesh-eating demons, by flesh-eating, it means human flesh-eating.

Comment: Can the Etymology of the term be explained?